# Can´t cross compile rnx2rtkp from rtklib2.4.3b29 to raspberry pi3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3

Using Ubuntu 17.10 and rtklib2.4.3b29. 
i am trying to cross compile rnx2rtkp:

```
'CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make'
```

gives me the

```
error: '../../../lib/iers/gcc/iers.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized'.
```

But when i install gfortrans and cross compile 'iers.a' just like:

```
'F77= arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran make'
```

it gives me the same error (neither 'gfortran-arm-linux-gnueabihf' did the job). I did the same job (except compiling iers.a cause the other moduls dont need that) with rtkrcv, str2str, and convbin without any problems. Don´t know what´s the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Went there and downloaded the CCompilers:

```
https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian
```

Went to the iers.a folder:

```
'../../../lib/iers/gcc/iers.a
```

and entered the makefile. In the makefile I put:

```
F77=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran
```

and executed the makefile.

Then i went back to rnx2rtkp folder and did again:

```
'CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make'
```

It finally worked. 
Note that i did `make clean` before i executed the makefiles in a second time.